# Featured Image Link to next post?

Tags: post-thumbnails, next-post-link

Hello i wonder if anyone knows this is possible?

A post featured image click to view next post...?

For example..

```
<a href="next-post">
 <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails'); ?>
</a>
```

I assume its something from the WordPress pagination, as when it gets to the final post/image it needs to go back to the first one.

Any idea if it can be done?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for your single.php template:

```
<?php
$next_post = get_adjacent_post( false,'',false );
if( isset($next_post->ID) ):
    $next_id = $next_post->ID;
else:
    $next_post = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=1&post_type=photo&order=ASC' );
    $next_id = $next_post->post->ID;
endif;
?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_id ); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $next_id, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
    </a>
```

Comment: Thanks Milo, that doesn't seem to work though :(

I'm using it on a single-photo.php for the custom post type photo.

The usual <li><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'twentyten' ) . ' prev' ); ?></li>
<li><?php next_post_link( '%link', 'next ' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '' ); ?></li>

works though, fine..

Comment: @Jezthomp - I've modified it slightly to work with your custom post type (assuming it's called `photo`). I've tested here locally with a cpt to verify it's working. If you still can't get it to work, I'll have to see it in context of your theme code.

Comment: Brilliant that works great but is it possible just to get the link, not the image and link from the next page?

Then attaching that link to the featured image on the current page, not the featured image from the next page?

Comment: +1 for `get_adjacent_post();`. Hadn't heard of that function before, very useful!